# Can I use external OpenCl libraries?

Tags: opencl

I want to use some external libraries (http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) to perform some analytical tasks on Geometry objects(GIS). I want to perform these task using OpenCL on Cuda so that I can use the paralel power of GPU to perform these tasks in parallel on large set of data.So my question is:

1. Can I write kernel using these libraries?
2. Also How can I pass the objects of complex data structures of these libraries as an argument to the kernel/(in specific How can I create buffer of these complex objects??

Comment: What does it mean "OpenCL on CUDA" ?

Comment: CUDA and OpenCL are two completely different things. Which do you want to ask about? There isn't necessarily a single answer to your questions which applies to both.

Comment: I mean to say, I am developing for Nvidia graphic cards using OpenCL(or I don't know its true to say like building application using OpenCL above the Cuda Drivers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't use external libraries in OpenCL kernels. Remember, any kernels is required to be compiled when the OpenCl application runs because it can't know what platform it is running on beforehand.

Comment: While you can't use external libraries in the kernels, you can interface external libraries with OpenCL kernels easily and by passing device pointers between your kernels and the external libraries.  Google "opencl gpu libraries" to find some.

Answer (score 8):

An [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/) program mostly consists of two parts

1. Host code - This is regular C/C++ code that calls functions in the OpenCL runtime and works just like any other code. This code needs to interface with any third-party libraries that may provide your program with (complex) data. It will also need to translate these complex data types to a set of simple data types ([scalar](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/scalarDataTypes.html), [vector](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/vectorDataTypes.html), [other](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/otherDataTypes.html)) that can be processed by piece 2.
2. Kernel code - The consists of a compiler that can convert a text/binary representation of a restricted kernel language (based on C99) to object code that can run on the target platform. This language and compiler has many [restrictions](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/restrictions.html) including the fact that you cannot include/link in external libraries (*maybe possible with [native kernel that is runnable on the host CPU](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNativeKernel.html)*)

It is upto your host code to [compile/setup the kernel](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateProgramWithSource.html), fetch/set up the data from any library/source, translate it into the appropriate scalar, vector or other data types permissible in an OpenCL kernel, [run the kernel(s)](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html) that process the data and get the results back from the compute device to the host (if necessary) and then translate those simple data types back to whatever form required for consumption by the rest of the code.

**So no** - you cannot directly use a regular C++ library **from inside the kernel**. But you can do whatever you want to in the *host code*.

Comment: Your first point is wrong (or at least doesn't correspond to question #1 above). You can't just use any host library inside a CUDA or OpenCL kernel. Neither programming model even supports the concept of external linkage at present.

Comment: But I read in this post http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=161786&st=0&p=1016769&hl=header&fromsearch=1&#entry1016769 that I can include the header files.Is it not gonna work for me????

Comment: I can include the headers for a library written for an ARM processor on my x86, but the library wont work. Similarly you can include the header of an x86 library in a kernel, but it doesn't mean it'll run on a GPU. (A rather over simplified example, but you get the point. The library needs to be written specifically for OpenCL / CUDA)

Comment: @talonmies I didn't say USE the libraries inside of OpenCL (I don't even understand how someone could think that). I should know, I have written my own bindings. I said **Yes, you can use any library you want with OpenCL or CUDA. They are simply computation libraries and are not concerned with what data you want to process or where that data comes from**

Comment: @PaulS - I didn't think that the OP wants to directly use the library inside a kernel. I have clarified my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @ananthonline: I read your points 1. and 2. as responses to questions 1 and 2 and that first part is *extremely* ambiguous at best. The first question is "1. Can I write **kernel** using these libraries" and you respond "1. Yes, you can use any library you want with OpenCL....". I would have another go at clarifying it if I were you.

Comment: @ananthonline: You'd be surprised what weird and wonderful ideas people have about OpenCL ;-)

Comment: Let me give this one more shot :)

Comment: @ananthonline,@talonmies,@PaulS :Thanks a lot guys for all your help.Actually I am totally new to this stuff and I have seriously bad misconception about the openCl thing.But you all cleraed up my doubts.Thanks again :)